# How to create all agents at once by a database?

Tags: anylogic

I'm generating my agents in anylogic based on a database table that I've created. In this DB I have some characteristics of my agent. This agent is supposed to be my "scheduling agent", since my focus is on rescheduling, it is important that my production orders are saved as agents in a queue. My problem is that when generating the agents, firstly I can't tell the system to generate all of them at once (so like "import" the line of my DB and transform each line into an agent with characteristics).
I tried doing it by adding 1s difference between every production order, but, when the last date is reached, my simulation gives an error and stops working. Could someone help me achieve my task? Do you think there would be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure 100% what you are trying to do, but I have a similar problem I think that I have solved this way.

I have a database of batches that I want to load all at once.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHHsQ.png)

This is going to load the batches one at a time with 0 interarrival time. This means that batches will flow continuously. Also important is the Limited number of arrivals option, which will stop the loading when the end of the database is reached.

Also, after the source, I added a queue with Maximum capacity set to infinite.

Hope that helps

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you